# python (idle) - Form given name, how to make in to a username

Tags: python

How to form a for loop?

For example, I want to run a for loop when there is a two words or three words in a name.

I need to make `for` loop for different number of names. 
For example, for two words, `saint christopher` to get just the `s` from `saint` and get `christopher` to get the result of `schristopher`.

Another example, `kyrie andrew irving`, I want to get `k` from `kyrie`, `a` from `andrew` and `irving` to get the result of `kairving`.

Given:

```
saint christopher
kyrie andrew irving
```

Result:

```
schristopher
kairving
```

I have done:

```
s = ("saint christopher", "kyrie andrew irving")
for s >= 2:
    first = s.split()
    separate = list(first[0])
    secondword = first[1]
    firstletter = separate[0]
    print(firstletter+secondword)
```

Where should I fix?

Comment: Note Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Please put down your code so we can help specifically on the code. And also read https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to ask a proper question.

Comment: You need to read a tutorial on basic python. The syntax of your for loop is wrong. Your code inside the for loop is not far off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish is fairly simple, and you get pretty close to it in the code in your question, even though your for loop syntax is off. Here is what you need:

```
names = ['kyrie andrew irving', 'saint christopher']

for item in names:
    name_sep = item.split(' ')
    username = ""
    for i in name_sep[0:-1]:
        username += i[0]
    username += name_sep[-1]
    print(username)
```

Let me walk you through it, Line by Line:

1. Start out with a list of names
2. Iterate over the list
3. Split the name into a list, using space to determine where to make a new element
4. Assign an empty string to be our user name
5. Iterate over all the separated names except the last one
6. Add their first letter to the username
7. Add the last item in the separated names to the username
8. Print the username

I recommend you read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/). It is a tutorial from the official python docs themselves. It should give you a basic grasp of syntax and how to use python in general.

Answer (score 1):

```
def make_username(name):
    return ''.join(x[0].lower() if i != len(name.split()) - 1 else x.lower() for i, x in enumerate(name.split()))

>>> make_username('saint christopher')
'schristopher'
>>> make_username('kyrie andrew irving')
'kairving'
>>> make_username('holly mother of god')
'hmogod'
```

...this will make a username for a name consisting of arbitrary amount of subnames. It takes first letter of every subname, except the last one where it takes the whole subname.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Steampunkery, your comments helped me alot!

I have edited my coding to

```
for line in infile:
    first = line.lower().split()
    username=""
    for i in first[0:-1]:
        username+=i[0]
    newusername+= first[-1]
    lastname = newusername[:9]
    print(lastname)
```